# What 'ChatOps' books and resources are available?

Tags: toolchain, operating-model, operations, chatops

We have defined what ChatOps is in the form of the following question:

- [What are ChatOps approach use cases of production infrastructure management?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/675/397):

  > Practically it means something very different to each team using it.  So much so that Atlassian have put together what could be considered to be a [Chat maturity model](https://blog.hipchat.com/2016/02/05/chatops-guide-evolution-adoption-significance/).
  >
  > 1. **Sputnik**: Trying chat out to see how it works.
  > 2. **Mercury**: Starting to move to chat.
  > 3. **Gemini**: Chat as the primary source of communication, experimenting with bots.
  > 4. **Apollo**: Chat as the nexus of communication and work, including bots.
  > 5. **Elon Musk**: Chat is the primary centre of mission critical work.

What other books and resources are available that describe the people, process and tools used to implement ChatOps within an organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/exAspArk/awesome-chatops) 'awesome' chat ops resource collection.

> ### Articles
>
> - [So, What is ChatOps? And How do I Get Started?](https://www.pagerduty.com/blog/what-is-chatops/) – ChatOps concepts and tools.
> - [What is ChatOps? A guide to its evolution, adoption, and significance](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2016/01/what-is-chatops-adoption-guide/) – ChatOps and its adoption by HipChat Evangelist.
> - [How ChatOps can revolutionize your business](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3062703/devops/how-chatops-can-revolutionize-your-business.html) – Benefits of using ChatOps, tools, current trend and the future.
> - [8 Reasons Why ChatOps Isn't Working At Your Company](https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/8-reasons-why-chatops-isnt-working-at-your-company) – The insight on why ChatOps might not be optimized at your company, and some advice
>     how to make it work.
> - [When ChatOps Goes From Cool to Critical](http://blog.librato.com/posts/chatops-critical) – Some considerations of ChatOps at Librato.
>
> ### Videos
>
> - [ChatOps at GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NST3u-GjjFw) + [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/jnewland/chatops-at-github) – The
>     first public talk on the subject by Jesse Newland.
> - [ChatOps: Technology and Philosophy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhzxnY7FIvg) – James
>     Fryman of Stackstorm about the philosophy, best practices for
>     implementing and maintaining ChatOps.
> - [The Rise of ChatOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D5HgI4IH10) + [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/jimmycuadra/the-rise-of-chatops) –
>     From the first ChatOps San Francisco meetup by Jimmy Cuadra.
> - [ChatOps: Augmented Reality for Ops](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCVvYCjvoZI) – How Github use
>     chat to improve situational awareness during incidents, to share
>     knowledge, to coordinate activities, and much more.
> - [Living in the Future with ChatOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Heo5YtRikds) +
>     [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/esigler/living-in-the-future-with-chatops)
>     – A quick summary of PagerDuty's ChatOps journey by Eric Sigler.
> - [Incident Management from the Future](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFkfMn2P8ysA) +
>     [slides](https://cloud.app.box.com/s/xm8ni5b61iyuk0nclq7jcvtkhkzcepdx)
>     – How Michael Ansel manages incidents via chat at Box.
> - [ChatOps San Francisco YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAvvR4g9fodNAS61Ep_XnMg) –
>     More videos from each meetup.
> - [Installing Hubot on Windows with PowerShell DSC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gh-vYprIo7c) - Using the Hubot
>     PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC) resource to install Hubot
>     on Windows.
> - [Embrace ChatOps, stop installing deployment software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZ3UfwBACIo) +
>     [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/geshan/embrace-chatops-stop-installing-deployment-software-larcon-eu-2016)
> - A talk from Laracon EU 2016 about how to leverage ChatOps for automated deployment using Hubot.
>
> ### Books
>
> - [ChatOps For Dummies](https://victorops.com/chatops-for-dummies/) – A high-level guide to understanding the origins    of the practice, the benefits and tools needed to get
>     started.
> - [ChatOps – Managing Operations in Group Chat](https://victorops.com/knowledge-drop/devops-docs/chatops-managing-operations-group-chat/) – The key ChatOps    concepts and technologies by Jason Hand.

Comment: Yes, it's a link to a huge number of other links which are Chat Ops re sources. The link is a git repo, where others can add more Chat ops re sources links through PRs.

Comment: @Bash Welcome to the site :)  Please elaborate further on why you think it's an awesome collection

Comment: It indeed is an awesome collection, @Bash. I've bookmarked that link right away.

Answer (score 3):

One of the [people active](https://www.arresteddevops.com/chatops/) in ChatOps community is Jason Hand from [VictorOps](https://victorops.com/chatops/), who wrote a book published by O'Reilly called [Managing Operations in Group Chat](http://www.oreilly.com/webops-perf/free/chatops.csp). This book is available for free as part of their content marketing campaign. The previous [ChatOps for Dummies](https://victorops.com/chatops-for-dummies/) is no longer available and is replaced by the above book.

You should definitely take a look at [Slack Apps](https://slack.com/apps), especially the Developer Tools. There is [article](https://stackstorm.com/2015/06/24/ansible-chatops-get-started-%F0%9F%9A%80/) by [SlackStorm](https://stackstorm.com) on how to integrate Ansible and Slack.

You might also monitor the subreddit on [chatops](https://www.reddit.com/r/chatops/). There is a long sidebar of resources including the video from GitHub ChatOps presentation and many more.

I would also recommend to look at [Cog](http://operable.io/cog.html) from [operable.io](http://operable.io) and the [Cog Book](http://cog-book.operable.io).